# groupby on sparse matrix with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I build a `scipy` sparse matrix `S` with `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()`. The matrix `S` has 10^6 rows for 500 columns.

I also have a `numpy` array `A` with 10^6 values as follows:

```
A = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,8,...]
```

I want to do a group by on the sparse matrix `S` following the groups written in the array `A`, and use `numpy.sum()` as an aggregation function.

How can I do? Of course, I everything needs to fit in memory, so I am forced to use sparse matrix for `S`.

Comment: Demonstrate what you want to do with a pair of small arrays.  Then we can think about how it can be adapted to a sparse one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the indices are increasing (as appears to be from your example), you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on an [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) of the list. For each group, use [numpy's indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

The loop could look like this:

```
import itertools
import operator

for g, inds in itertools.groupby(enumerate(A), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    ...
```

and the `...` should be replaced by code that does whatever you want with `S`. To see why, note the following sample:

```
for g, inds in itertools.groupby(enumerate(A), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
     print g, list([i[0] for i in inds])
```

which produces

```
1 [0, 1]
2 [2, 3, 4]
3 [5]
4 [6]
5 [7]
6 [8, 9]
7 [10]
8 [11, 12, 13]
```

You can tell that the first item is the group, and the second is a list of indices. Numpy has extensive utilities to slice & index given such lists.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see `S` in your code? The groups are in `A`, but the data I want to group is in `S`.

Comment: Um, yes, it's "hiding" in the ``...``. That's where I suggest you put the code accessing ``S``.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't figgure it out by myself. I read 10 times the groupby doc.

Comment: See if the clarification helps you.